# can i use convolutional neural network for measuring algal concentration (spirulina platensis)?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, video-processing

We are working on a research about algal growth specifically about spirulina plantesis and we are planning to use convolutional neural network but we lack knowledge about it, is it possible to use CNN and image/video processing to measure the algal concentration?

Comment: Could you upload some images of the different concentrations?